# Remove slash added after .htm extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Errors found in WMT are showing files like

```
/brands/abc.htm/northis.htm
northis.htm
```

does not exist, and is created from `abc.htm`, but with broken images and incorrect links.
I don't know where the links to such pages are coming from, and I've tried many solutions without success.

For instance,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm/$ http://example.com/euro/brands/$1.htm [L,R=301]
```

which does not work, or works sometimes.
This works, but as there are a great many pages, it's not a viable solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/euro/brands/sachs.htm/(.*)$ http://example.com/euro/brands/sachs.htm
```

I suspect there's an error in the root htaccess, but cannot see it. The rules above are in /brands/

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is and what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*\.html?)/.*$ http://example.com/$1
```